# TeamCity NuGet installer build step fails

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, nuget

I'm trying to configure TeamCity to work with NuGet. So far - no luck.
I configured 4 build steps:

- Download NuGet packages
- Build
- Run unit-tests
- Check for code duplications.

However, when I trigger the build, I can't even get past first build step.
I configured TC to download missing NuGet packages. When I run the build, TC says:

> Failed to find repositories.config at {here_is_my_path}".

I understand that the problem is I use this VS feature called `Enable NuGet package restore` - so, there is no such file as `repositories.config` in my solution folder and that's why TC can't find it and build is failing. So, how am I supposed to configure TC then? Any ideas and help is appreciated.

I'm using .NET 4.0, VS2010 and TeamCity 7 if it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it working by including \packages\repositories.config in my Git repository and using **NuGet Install** step to update the packages, and an **MsBuild** step pointed at my .sln file.  To get Git to actually pick up the config file without also adding all of the other stuff I added the following to .gitignore:

```
packages/*
!repositories.config
```

Comment: You don't need to add all the packages, the whole point should be that they're downloaded before you build. That way you don't bloat your repo with binaries. http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

Answer (score 1):

I found out that TeamCity team didn't envision such situation, so someone requested this as a feature almost 4 weeks ago. I voted up, let's see if it can make it to one of the upcoming releases. 
For anyone interested here's YouTrack issue link: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-20525

Comment: apparently, the feature request was popular, so the feature is currently under development